# Мне было интересно как

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис

> Он пошел добывать пропитание. Мне было интересно как, но у меня была задача зажечь костер.

Нужны какие-либо знаки перед словом "как"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Запятая перед «как» не нужна. В [Полном академическом справочнике под редакцией Лопатина](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=134#pp134) о подобных конструкциях сказано:

Запятая между главной частью и придаточной, присоединяемой простым союзом или союзным словом, не ставится, если придаточная часть усечена до одного союзного слова (одиночно употребленное союзное слово теряет функцию придаточного предложения): Учащимся назначили экзамен, но не уточнили когда; Со стороны проспекта кто-то шел — издали было неясно кто (Пелев.).

Answer (score 1):

Запятой не нужно. Не могу найти ссылки, но знаю, что если фраза заканчивается союзным словом, то запятую перед ним не ставят. Если же идёт пояснение, тогда запятая уже становится нужна.